# Issue while parsing bencoded data?

Tags: java, parsing, encoding, arraylist

I have some torrent file with list of announce urls, f.e. this is the part of it:

```
announce-listll68:http://iptorrents.com:2790/b6d18a815ab4421a86de672d6833369d/announceel67:http://iptorrents.me:2710/b6d18a815ab4421a86de672d6833369d/announceel67:http://iptorrents.ru:6969/b6d18a815ab4421a86de672d6833369d/announceee
```

So here is one array with key «announce-list» which contains three elements (bencoded data, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode).
So I am using BDecoder.java class from Aeltis to decode it. While parsing I am getting the next values of Map:

```
{created by=[B@141d683, announce=[B@16a55fa, encoding=[B@32c41a, announce-list=[[[B@e89b94], [[B@13e205f], [[B@1bf73fa]], comment=[B@5740bb, creation date=1310060702, info={pieces=[B@5ac072, name=[B@109a4c, length=34209795, piece length=65536, private=1}}
```

So announce list filled with some hashes. So how can I convert it to normal string (such as «http://iptorrents.com:2790/b6d18a815ab4421a86de672d6833369d/announce»)? Or it's some algorithm issue in BDecoder.java?

This is the method of upper class to decode data: http://pastebin.com/HimqF0ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned in your case is a generic Map, with no type defined. So I suppose when you try to print the values, only the addresses are printed. Try casting the values of the Map to String and that should do the trick.

Best regards,

Baptiste